# Java ArrayList Help!

Tags: java, object, arraylist, jframe, tostring

I am working on learning java a little, and i found this question in a java text book on Google books, I have been working on it for a while, and for some reason these seems like it should be simple. Anyone bored and would like to show me what this is suppose to look like in Java code??

```
(Using ArrayList) Write a program that creates an ArrayList, adds a Loan
object, a Date object, a string, a JFrame object, and a Circle object to the list,
and uses a loop to display all the elements in the list by invoking the object’s
toString() method.
```

Comment: wow sounds like homework but maybe isn't this time. Are you referring to this book http://books.google.at/books?id=juuPxtSCg50C&lpg=PT387&ots=TxQaiubSy4&dq=Write%20a%20program%20that%20creates%20an%20ArrayList%2C%20adds%20a%20Loan%20object%2C%20a%20Date%20object%2C%20a%20string%2C%20a%20JFrame%20object%2C%20and%20a%20Circle%20object&pg=PT387#v=onepage&q=Write%20a%20program%20that%20creates%20an%20ArrayList,%20adds%20a%20Loan%20object,%20a%20Date%20object,%20a%20string,%20a%20JFrame%20object,%20and%20a%20Circle%20object&f=false

Comment: yes thats the book. not home work... dont have the time for school.. maybe if i went i would have to ask this question LOL

Comment: grrr... (without reading it) this is why I hate books that "teach" programming.  The odds of you _ever_ wanting to create a list that holds those sorts of things is very very very very very small.  I do not understand why books teach things that are generally bad.

Comment: @TofuBeer the point is to understand that all these objects have a toString() that does different things.It's teaching the concept, not teaching programming.

Comment: Nothing says you cannot teach with good examples that are still clear!

Answer (score 3):

This code assumes that the various objects in question have no-parameter constructors. Else just stick the parameters in appropriately:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(new Loan());
list.add(new Date());
list.add(new String());
list.add(new JFrame());
list.ad(new Circle());

for (Object obj : list)
{
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object> list= new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add("A String");
list.add(new JFrame());
list.add(new YourCircleObject());
(...)
for(Object o:list)
 {
 System.out.println(o.toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without giving you the exact code (you are trying to learn Java, right?) the goal of the exercise is to show you that every type of object in Java extends from the root base class Object.  There are certain things that you can do on any instance of Object, no matter what it's concrete implementation (such as toString() for instance).

Additionally the exercise is also teaching you about the Collections API and how you can build collections of heterogeneous objects.  Spend a little time looking at the [Collections API documentation.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html)

Comment: well i dont have a teach to show me examples and what not.. so i will take what i see here and try to apply to other circumstances. thats how i learn

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `Loan` and `Circle` classes don't exist in the Java library, you'll have to define your own. All the others live in various packages such as `java.util` or `javax.swing`. If Eclipse didn't automatically do the `import`s for me, I'd use Google to find the package names I need for the import statements.

That done, you can instantiate all of them using `new`. First you create an `ArrayList`, then you do something like

`myList.add(new JFrame())`

to add those other objects to the list.

Then you use a `for` loop to run through the list and output the elements using `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise9_6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new Loan());
        list.add(new Date());
        list.add(new javax.swing.JFrame());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
          System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```